# AWS API Gateway Proxy with many lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, proxy

I´ve been using AWS API Gateway for quite a long time, and last month I started using it by calling my C# ASPNET inside a Lambda function through a proxy integration.
And that was fine.
Then I needed another lambda function with a different ASPNET API, and for this one, I had to create another API Gateway with another proxy integration.
I´m reaching the fourth lambda.

```
MyFirstApi, with resources:
    /{proxy+}    ..... pointing to lambda 1

MySecondApi, with resources:
    /{proxy+}    ..... pointing to lambda 2

MyThirdApi, with resources:
    /{proxy+}    ..... pointing to lambda 3

MyFourthApi, with resources:
    /{proxy+}    ..... pointing to lambda 4
```

I´m trying to guess if there is a way to have one single API Gateway, with multiple resources, one for each lambda function, each one a proxy integration.
Example:

```
MySingleApi, with resources:
  /function1/{proxy+}    ..... pointing to lambda 1 
  /function2/{proxy+}    ..... pointing to lambda 2 
  /function3/{proxy+}    ..... pointing to lambda 3 
  /function4/{proxy+}    ..... pointing to lambda 4
```

I can create them, and point each one to a different lambda function, but the APIGatewayRequest object carries that "functionN" string as part of the path parameter, which is not mapped inside the ASPNET API controller/method routing, causing a 404 error.

**Am I missing something here ?**

Comment: today I´ve discovered the "API Gateway Custom Domain Name" feature, which can be used for the purposes I was trying to do in a single-API-multi-lambda approach.

Comment: Is this fixed? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create multiple resources from the root path without proxy settings.
2. Register a resource with proxy settings under each resource.

The settings I worked on are as follows.

[image]